# What is DATA_TRANSFER_NETWORK on an android phone?

Tags: wi-fi

We have a Moto G stylus 2023 and there is an option in the WiFi menu for DATA_TRANSFER_NETWORK.  What does that mean and what is it used for?

Comment: [Seen this?](https://www.motorola-support.com/us-en/?page=device/motorola/moto-g-stylus/topic/data/transfer-data-from-phone-to-computer-windows/10)